# Create words and its position in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

Hi I am trying to create string which will have words and its position as it appear in the input string. I am able to do it in python using below code -

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

s = 'Create a string with position from a string a' 
wp = defaultdict(list)

for n, k in enumerate(s.split()):
    wp[k].append(n+1)
    
raw_output = re.search('{(.*)}', str(wp)).group(1).replace('[','').replace(']','')
final_output = re.sub("(\d), '", r"\1 '", raw_output)
```

And output is

```
"'Create': 1 'a': 2, 7, 9 'string': 3, 8 'with': 4 'position': 5 'from': 6"
```

How can I do the same in pyspark?

Answer (score 0):

Pyspark has few additional concepts you might need to revisit, using RDD apis is the best
for your problem statement.

Here is a code snippet that should work for you.

```
def positional_encoder(sentence):
  words=sentence.split(" ")
  indexes=list(range(0,len(words)))
  return list(zip(words,indexes))

data_rdd = sc.parallelize(["Create a string with position from a string a"])
words_index=data_rdd.map(lambda sentence: positional_encoder(sentence))

## Just for debugging:
words_index.collect()  ## Remove this after debugging
```

Comment: Thanks for response. It is giving below result. [[('Create', 0),
  ('a', 1),
  ('string', 2),
  ('with', 3),
  ('position', 4),
  ('from', 5),
  ('a', 6),
  ('string', 7),
  ('a', 8)]]  . Which is little different from required output.